# Do not receive the appropriate answer from $.ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use **$.ajax** function to get some contents, then I need to print out some special tags from that, but no data is there! I am doing it so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1/demo/w/?p=97",
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(out){
            mine = $(out).find(".especial");
            $("body").html(mine);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Of course when I print out the content totally there is no problem.
like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1/demo/w/?p=97",
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(out){
            mine = out;
            $("body").html(mine);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

It seems the problem is that I could not declare `out` as a jQuery object like `$(out)` and thus the `find()` function does not work. Or maybe the problem is something else?

Comment: Are you declaring mine as a variable?

Comment: show "out" markup please :)

Comment: yes "mine" is a variable. but no difference whether to use "var" or not!

Comment: "out" is html markup. some codes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded out the answer myself.
there is no error in the code!

problem is that JQuery 1.9.1 witch i was using does not support the code!
so i used JQuery 1.7.1 instead and the problem was solved!

then after i again used JQuery 1.9.1 with the help of migration code
here:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js

**the problem was solved**
:-)

Answer (score 0):

I am betting you need to switch `find()` with `filter()`.

```
mine = $(out).filter(".especial");
```

OR

```
mine = $("<div/>").html(out).find(".especial");
```

Comment: thank you dear epascarello
i tested what you said but no success out there